# How to handle Rolling updates deployment strategy for RWO volume service?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod

We have hosted service in AKS which has RWO volumes with Deployment strategy as Recreate.
We recently went live with this new service and we have many features/issues to be delivered everyday. Since the deployment strategy is Recreate, business team is experiencing some down time (2 min max) but it is annoying. Is there a better approach to manage RWO volumes with rolling update strategy ?

Comment: Can you say a little more about your use case?  Can you store the data somewhere else, like a separate relational database container, that would allow concurrent access from multiple pods (particularly during an upgrade)?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Little background - The service with RWO is cms application, there is a chance that when we are deploying, the pages in the browser, few sections might have edited/deleted by business team. agree.  there is an option of persistence volume we can use but in this case I am not very sure..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two types of strategies to choose from when specifying the way of updating your deployments:

- [Recreate Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#recreate-deployment): All existing Pods are killed before new ones are created.
- [Rolling Update Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#rolling-update-deployment): The Deployment updates Pods in a rolling update fashion.

The default and more recommended one is the `.spec.strategy.type==RollingUpdate`. See the examples below:

```
spec:
  replicas: 2
  strategy:
   type: RollingUpdate
   rollingUpdate:
     maxSurge: 1
     maxUnavailable: 0
```

In this example there would be one additional Pod (`maxSurge: 1`) above the desired number of 2, and the number of available Pods cannot go lower than that number (`maxUnavailable: 0`).

Choosing this config, the Kubernetes will spin up an additional Pod, then stop an “old” one. If there’s another Node available to deploy this Pod, the system will be able to handle the same workload during deployment. If not, the Pod will be deployed on an already used Node at the cost of resources from other Pods hosted on the same Node.

You can also try something like this:

```
spec:
  replicas: 2
  strategy:
   type: RollingUpdate
   rollingUpdate:
     maxSurge: 0
     maxUnavailable: 1
```

With the example above there would be no additional Pods (`maxSurge: 0`) and only a single Pod at a time would be unavailable (`maxUnavailable: 1`).

In this case, Kubernetes will first stop a Pod before starting up a new one. The advantage of that is that the infrastructure doesn’t need to scale up but the maximum workload will be less.

If you chose to use the percentage values for `maxSurge` and `maxUnavailable` you need to remember that:

- `maxSurge` - the absolute number is calculated from the percentage by **rounding up**
- `maxUnavailable` - the absolute number is calculated from percentage by **rounding down**

With the `RollingUpdate` defined correctly you also have to make sure your  applications provide endpoints to be queried by Kubernetes that return the app’s status. Below it's a `/greeting` endpoint, that returns an HTTP 200 status when it’s ready to handle requests, and HTTP 500 when it’s not:

```
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /greeting
    port: 8080
  initialDelaySeconds: 5
  periodSeconds: 5
  successThreshold: 1
  timeoutSeconds: 1
```

- `initialDelaySeconds` - Time (in seconds) before the first check for readiness is done.
- `periodSeconds` - Time (in seconds) between two readiness checks after the first one.
- `successThreshold` - Minimum consecutive successes for the probe to be considered successful after having failed. Defaults to 1. Must be 1 for liveness. Minimum value is 1.
- `timeoutSeconds` - Number of seconds after which the probe times out. Defaults to 1 second. Minimum value is 1.

More on the topic of liveness/readiness probes can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/).

These are only examples but they should give you the idea of that particular update strategy that could be used in order to eliminate the possibility of downtime.

Comment: - Thanks a lot for the details answers. Yes, I made changes as you suggested and services are working as expected.

Comment: This answer absolutely do not take in consideration the question about rwo volumes.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, RWO Volume with RollingUpdate Strategy may cause Multi-Attach Error for Volume.

RWO restricts the volume’s usage to a single pod at a time. So there is a situation where the old pod isn’t terminated until the new one is up and running. The old pod clings to the PVC volume, preventing the new pod from initializing.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35366215)